# The onLoad event is never triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I'm trying to figure it out why the onload event never gets called. Everything builds without an error, similar onLoad event works in a different component.
    export class Work extends React.Component {

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      allImgLoaded: false,
      boxHovered: false,
      projects: projects
    }
this.handleWorkLoad = this.handleWorkLoad.bind(this);

  }

componentWillMount() {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}

handleWorkLoad() {
  console.log("called");
  this.setState({
    allImgLoaded: true
  })
}

  render() {

    return (
    <div className={this.state.allImgLoaded ? "work" : "work invisible"} onLoad={this.handleWorkLoad}>

        </div>    
    );
  }
};

export default Work;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react you have the componentDidMount method which gives you the ability to run specific code after the component finished it's loading phase:

```
class Work extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
          allImgLoaded: false,
          boxHovered: false,
          projects: projects
        }
        this.handleWorkLoad = this.handleWorkLoad.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount() {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleWorkLoad()
    }

    handleWorkLoad() {
        console.log("called");
        this.setState({
            allImgLoaded: true
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className={this.state.allImgLoaded ? "work" : "work invisible"}>
            </div>    
        );
    }
};

export default Work;
```

There is no `onLoad` event for `div` elements in react.

Comment: what if the div is a parent of several images ? That is the case here, although i have cut it out. Do i have to put onLoad on every image and count it to know if all are loaded? feels unnatural

Comment: The `img` element in react has the `onload` event, however `div` elements don't. As for your question - yes, you will need to do so for every img tag (which will be exactly the same case without react)